# Windows PHP 5.6 built in server SQLite3

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, php-builtin-server

I have PHP 5.6 installed on windows 7 and I used the built in server to run websites locally for testing.  I want to connect to a Sqlite3 file and I've uncommented the appropriate lines in the php.ini file in my C:\Program Files\php folder.  I still get this error when trying to view the page on my local server:
 `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\Users\USERX\Documents\pageloadbasic.php:13 Stack trace: #0`
 `C:\Users\USERX\Documents\pageloadbasic.php(13): PDO->__construct('sqlite:db/lhblo...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\USERX\Documents\pageloadbasic.php on line 13`

Why do I get this error?

A couple of notes: my phpinfo file shows:

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\Windows`(for some reason this always defaults to C:\Windows even if there is not php.ini file in there)

`Loaded Configuration File  C:\Program Files\php\php.ini`

But there is no php.ini file in C:\Windows.  Also, my php folder does not include a php_pdo.dll in the ext folder, but I added one that I extracted from the pecl-5.0.5-Win32 archive as instructed in some other sites.

I added `extension=php_pdo.dll` in my php.ini file.

I uncommented `extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll`.

I uncommented `extension=php_sqlite3.dll`.

I have these two lines in my php.ini which related to sqlite:

`[sqlite]
; http://php.net/sqlite.assoc-case
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0` (I did not change anything on these two lines because I'm not sure what it is for...)

`[sqlite3]
sqlite3.extension_dir = "ext"` (on this line I added the "ext" directory as suggested on another post)

I have this in my php code to connect to my db file using pdo: 
`$db = new PDO('sqlite:db/xxxxx.db');`

What am I missing?  What do I need to do to get PDO to work with Sqlite3?

Comment: Do those extension DLLs actually exist? Are they in the right place? Are they the right version? Turn you error_reporting up in `php.ini` [not using `ini_set` in your script] and you should see the error messages if you're having any of these problems.

Comment: Yes, I checked and all those dlls exist in ext. My error reporting is on too.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Even though I had properly uncommented all my dlls, and uncommented the `sqlite3.extension_dir = "ext"`, you need to specifically uncomment the windows ext location on the line following `; On windows:'`
extension_dir = "ext"`
And then restart your server.